# Position figcaption beside an image

Tags: html, css, figure

I want to add a `figcaption`, which is a paragraph explaining my image, and I want to put it beside the image itself (if the paragraph is too long I'd like the text to go under the image after finishing the space beside). I searched for the commands, also CSS, but I did not find anything.

Comment: did you see this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp

?

Answer (score 2):

Float the image left, and set `overflow: auto` to  make sure the figure will contain the float:

```css
figure {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

figure img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<figure >
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/75" />
  
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```